# Who are the Lego Certified Professionals?

Tags: lego-group, afol, lcp

So, I was just watching Lego Masters, and it's mentioned that the show's judge, Ryan "Brickman" McNaught, is one of fourteen Lego Certified Professionals in the world. I was wondering who those fourteen people were. I found [this](http://thebrickblogger.com/2015/06/lego-certified-professionals-who-are-they/) article from in the answers one of the other questions on this site; however, it only lists 12 individuals, so it's clearly not an up-to-date list. I also found [this post](https://lan.lego.com/news/overview/what-is-the-lego-certified-professional-program-all-about-r245/) from 2019 on an official Lego website that states that there are currently 20 Lego Certified Professionals, not 14.

Is there a complete, up-to-date list of the identities of the Lego Certified Professionals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**November 2021 update**

New LCP in Russia has been [announced](https://lan.lego.com/news/overview/new-lcp-in-russia-r299/) - Vladimir Golubev.

Number of LCP's is now - 22 (listed below). TLG has details on all of the members, except Vladimir. You can find more information about each member on [the LEGO Certified Professionals](https://www.lego.com/en-us/aboutus/lego-certified-professionals/) webpage.

**Americas**

1. Robin Sather
2. Nathan Sawaya
3. Graeme Dymond

**Europe & Middle East**

1. Dirk Denoyelle
2. Georg Schmitt
3. Matija Puzar
4. Rene Hoffmeister
5. Kevin Hall
6. Ricardo Zangelmi
7. Luke Reveruzzi
8. Caspar Bennedsen
9. Balazs Doczy
10. Vladimir Golubev

**Asia-Pacific**

1. Prince (Shenghui) Jiang
2. Jumpei Mitsui
3. Wani Kim
4. Jae Won Lee
5. Wei Wei Shannon Gluckman
6. Nicholas Foo
7. Yenchih Huang
8. Andy Hung
9. Ryan McNaught

Comment: Graeme for sure is an LCP. Source: that LAN link and I know him personally. The official list page must be out of date. The most recent announcements for new LCPs have all been posted on lan.lego.com.

Comment: It wasn't specified which region Vladimir Aleksandrovich belongs to, but I assumed it is  going to be, most likely, "Europe & Middle East" where I've listed him.